# Should I use a single callout with a list or mulitple callout for each Account?

Tags: trigger, callout, future, queue

I wanted to Bulkify my code to be able to update/create a long list of account for which I need to callout to my api.

I know that I can't do more than 50 callouts per future methods.
But using Queueable Jobs I can't add up to 50 jobs to the queue.

So I'm sending the list of account inside a JSON with one CallOut :

Code In my trigger :

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (after insert, after update) {

List<Account> lstJson =new List<Account>();
for(Integer i=0;i<Trigger.new.size();i++){
    Account account = Trigger.new[i];
lstJson.add((account));
}

/// Then i send my list of account to my Future Task
Map<string, List<Account>> accountMap = new Map<string, List<Account>>();   
// Normally I should only Serialize the JSONLIst but our api has a problem...
accountMap.put('items', lstJson);
FutureTaskCreator.sendNotification(JSON.serialize(accountMap));
```

Then I call my API inside the callout :

```
public class FutureTaskCreator {

@future(callout=true)
public static void sendNotification(String json_string){
  //my code
}
}
```

Is it a good way to implement it ?
I've hit a limititation in both Queue and Callout...

Thanks for feedback to improve the method

Comment: did you consider chained queueables? this avoids the limit issue

Comment: Yes, but I reached the same type of limit I can't Queue as much as I want. I had trouble "splitting" the list.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to split the list of accounts into 5 batches of 10 each and invoking 5 queueable calls which will do the callout and rest of the processing.

```
List<Account> lstJson =new List<Account>();
```

Split the final list into 5 lists and call queueables 5 times

```
FutureTaskCreator.sendNotification(JSON.serialize(accountMap1));
FutureTaskCreator.sendNotification(JSON.serialize(accountMap2));
FutureTaskCreator.sendNotification(JSON.serialize(accountMap3));
FutureTaskCreator.sendNotification(JSON.serialize(accountMap4));
FutureTaskCreator.sendNotification(JSON.serialize(accountMap5));
```

Comment: I get the idea, but I don't think  it is elegant. So I would stick to my solution calling one time with a JSON containing the full list.

Comment: @Benoît, this will also be easy on other limits, again your call

Comment: What would be the limit ?

Comment: In your solution you talk about queuables, what do you mean by that ? About the code I should create a for loop where I split my list into as much need to not reach 50 calls ?